# how to return data from child window tp parent window in extjs?

Tags: extjs, childwindow

In a treepanel on Node click i'm opening a form (Ext.form.Panel) in child window (Ext.Window) to get the user input. In a form I have radio buttons and textfield and OK and Cancel buttons. on Ok click i want to close the window. after closing the window i want to access the form values on treepanel.

Answer (score -1):

Pass a function to the window when you create it (from your parent controller) and call it when you want to close the child window. i.e. when you press 'OK' button on the child window call this.readAndClose(form) where form is the your button.up('form).getForm().

```
var win = Ext.create('App.view.ChildWindow',{
                    readAndClose:function(form){
                        var name = form.findField('name').getValue();
                        //...process form field values and then close the window
                        this.close();
                    }
});
win.show();
```